# Delete lines where text after character is duplicated

Tags: text-processing

I have a list of IP ranges in the following format:

```
Long description:111.22.33.0-111.22.33.40
Another description:5.5.5.0-5.5.5.100
Yet another description:111.22.33.0-111.22.33.40
And another one:111.22.33.0-111.22.33.40
Something different:8.1.1.0-8.1.1.20
etc.
```

I'd like to delete lines having duplicate IP ranges, even when the "description" differs (e.g. only match text after the : character).

The example above should become:

```
Long description:111.22.33.0-111.22.33.40
Another description:5.5.5.0-5.5.5.100
Something different:8.1.1.0-8.1.1.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could ask `sort` for the unique lines based on the 2nd field, delimited by colons:

```
sort -u -t: -k2 < input > output
```

The hard work is done by `-u`, which:

> output(s) only the **first** of an equal run

(my emphasis)

Reference:

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort

Comment: Thanks, it works. To make things more complicated, would it be possible to also delete overlapping IP ranges? e.g. 111.22.33.0-111.22.33.40 includes 111.22.33.0-111.22.33.5 which should be deleted.

Comment: It would make it more complicated, since `sort -u` only deals with exact textual matches. I would recommend asking a separate question.