# Delete overlapping IP ranges in text file

Tags: text-processing

To expand on my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/453670/delete-lines-where-text-after-character-is-duplicated), I have a list of IP ranges in the format:

```
Long description:20.1.1.0-20.1.1.14
Another description:5.5.5.0-5.5.5.100
Yet another description:20.1.1.0-20.1.1.40
```

There are no duplicates, but I'd like to delete any overlapping IP ranges.

For example, in the above example, the first line should be deleted as its range is already included in the 3rd line.

**NOTE:** I need to keep the whole line (description included), not just the IP ranges.

Comment: Do the ranges have to be completely covered by another to be deleted; what if there is a partial overlap?

Comment: I think this will help with this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16986879/bash-script-to-list-all-ips-in-prefix

Comment: @JeffSchaller partial overlaps containing IPs not covered elsewhere should be kept.

Comment: What distro are you on? For Debian/Ubuntu - https://askubuntu.com/questions/878188/converting-a-range-of-ipv4-addresses-to-netmasks-using-bash.

Comment: @slm I wouldn't know how to adapt that solution to preserve the description field.

Comment: I'd just do this in python - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206679/check-if-two-cidr-addresses-intersect. The ipaddr library has a method called overlaps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with the input lines being reordered, I have a relatively simple solution using GNU Awk and the "sort" command. The basic idea is to convert the IP addresses to single numbers instead of dotted pairs, which makes it very easy to compare them, and to use the `-k` flag of sort which allows specifying that it should only sort specific fields.

For compactness, this also uses the GNU awk feature of coprocesses, which makes it very easy to process data before and after using `sort`:

**EDIT:** The `sort` commandline in the original version of this answer was slightly wrong: `sort -k2,3r` actually treats fields `2` and `3` as a single key, to be sorted in reverse order. `sort -k2,2n -k3,3rn` will do the necessary thing of first sorting by field `2` and using (reversed) field `3` as a tiebreaker:

```
# Run as: gawk -F: -f <thisfile.awk> <input file>
BEGIN {
  # Define the sort command that we will be using later as a variable
  # Sort by
  #   - the 1st ip, smallest-to-largest
  #   - the 2nd ip, largest-to-smallest
  sort="sort -n -t: -k2,2n -k3,3nr";
}

# For every line:
{
  # Store the individual components of the addresses into 'ips'
  match($2, /([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+)\
-([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+).([[:digit:]]+)/, ips);
  # Add the components together to get the IPs as a single number.
  # The print also uses : as the delimiter between the 2 IPS for simplicity
  print $1":"ips[4]+256*(ips[3]+256*(ips[2]+256*ips[1])) \
          ":"ips[8]+256*(ips[7]+256*(ips[6]+256*ips[5])) \
    |& sort
}

# After sending all lines to sort in the appropriate format
END {
  # Close sort's input stream, so that we can read its output
  close(sort, "to");
  # Keep track of the upper end of the previous range
  prevHigh=0;
  # Read & field-split all lines from sort's output
  while((sort |& getline) > 0) {
     # One range is contained in another if its low address is >= the
     # other's (guaranteed by the sort command) and its high address is <=
     # the other's. So, we should print this record when its high address is >
     # prevHigh:
    if ($3 > prevHigh) {
      print $1":"int($2/(256*256*256))%256"."int($2/(256*256))%256"." \
                 int($2/256)%256"."$2%256 \
              "-"int($3/(256*256*256))%256"."int($3/(256*256))%256"." \
                 int($3/256)%256"."$3%256 \
      # This is now the previous range
      prevHigh = $3
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However it seems to work partially, some ranges are missing: https://pastebin.com/raw/jdWWeGMg

Comment: Oh, sorry! Let me take a look at it.

Comment: @MarkRoi Please see the updated answer above---the `sort` command has been changed, which I think fixes your issue.

Comment: Excellent. Just tested on the real data (about 10K lines) and compared the results, worked flawlessly and quickly. Thank you so much!